# How can I rename and change the IP address of a Netapp Filer?

Tags: netapp

I have an old Netapp filer that I'm migrating all of the NTFS files off of to a new NAS.

I'm going to be setting the new NAS up with the same IP and CIFS server name as the old netapp filer.  This part I know how to do.

However, short of simply turning off the old netapp filer, is there a way I can change the IP and the name of the "CIFS server" on the old netapp filer so that I can leave it online for a few weeks if I have to grab files off of it or to do a final backup?

This is for data ontap 7.2

Comment: It's data ontap 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the ifconfig man page for ontap: http://ecserv1.uwaterloo.ca/netapp/man/man1/na_ifconfig.1.html

Here's one for the cifs commands: http://ecserv1.uwaterloo.ca/netapp/man/man1/na_cifs.1.html

changing your IP would be something like this (you would want to do this when logged in from the console in case it's not obvious):

```
# Get the name of the interface your current IP is assigned to, as well as 
# netmask, etc
ifconfig -a

# down the interface (i'm not actually sure if this is needed)
ifconfig INTERFACE down

# bring the interface back up with the new network info (substituting the
# correct values for INTERFACE, NETMASK, and ADDRESS)
ifconfig INTERFACE ADDRESS netmask NETMASK ip
```

You might also have to edit some files in the filer's etc/ dir to make the change persist across a reboot, as I said it's been a long time.  cd to the filer's etc and grep for the current IP to get an idea.

as for renaming the share...  Looks like you can't do a straight rename, you're in for deleting the old one and recreating it with the new name.  How about something like this:

```
# show the info about the current shares:
cifs shares

# change the share name
cifs shares -delete OLDSHARE

# add the new name with the same settings as the old
cifs shares -add NEWNAME [options]
```

See the na_cifs_shares man page for more infor on the options when you recreate the share (http://ecserv1.uwaterloo.ca/netapp/man/man1/na_cifs_shares.1.html)

Hope that helps somewhat...

Comment: Thank you.  Not wanting to rename the shares though...wanting to rename the actual "server" name.  so \\filer\shareA becomes \\filertemp\shareA

Comment: What the host thinks its name is would be the hostname command, plus maybe editing the filer's etc/hosts file.  Then an external DNS change as well.  As for what you mount it as, I'm not sure what to say - if I were mounting via NFS the name of the local mount would be 100% controlled by the mount command I ran (or the contents of fstab).  I think though that a DNS change and a hostname change on the filer would do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

To make the change persist across a reboot, first you have to read two files:

```
ontap1> rdfile /etc/rc
#Auto-generated by setup Fri Jan 25 07:18:17 GMT 2013
hostname ontap1
ifconfig e0a `hostname`-e0a mediatype auto flowcontrol full netmask 255.255.255.0 mtusize 9000
ifconfig e0b `hostname`-e0b mediatype auto flowcontrol full netmask 255.255.255.0 mtusize 9000
ifconfig e0c `hostname`-e0c mediatype auto flowcontrol full netmask 255.255.255.0 mtusize 9000
ifconfig e0d `hostname`-e0d mediatype auto flowcontrol full netmask 255.255.255.0 mtusize 9000
route add default 10.19.11.1 1
routed on
options dns.domainname fibra
options dns.enable on
options nis.enable off
savecore

ontap1> rdfile /etc/hosts
#Auto-generated by setup Fri Jan 25 07:18:17 GMT 2013
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost-stack
127.0.10.1  localhost-10 localhost-bsd
127.0.20.1  localhost-20 localhost-sk
19.19.11.51 ontap1 ontap1-e0a
10.19.11.52 ontap1-e0b
10.19.11.53 ontap1-e0c
10.19.11.54 ontap1-e0d
```

Now you can see, that first file sets the ip address of all interfaces, but the ip address values are taken from second file (/etc/hosts), then you have to modify the second file:

```
wrfile /etc/hosts
#Auto-generated by setup Fri Jan 25 07:18:17 GMT 2013
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost-stack
127.0.10.1  localhost-10 localhost-bsd
127.0.20.1  localhost-20 localhost-sk
10.19.11.51 ontap1 ontap1-e0a
10.19.11.52 ontap1-e0b
10.19.11.53 ontap1-e0c
10.19.11.54 ontap1-e0d
(Ctrl-c)
```

Now, you can reboot.